# Rails - Polymorphic Associations- Best Practices to handle optional association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a model `StockEntry` which belongs to a `stock_logable` for ex: `InvoiceItem`, `ReturnItem` etc. My model looks something like this:

```
belongs_to :stock_logable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
```

Now I need to handle the case of opening stock. This is how i handled it:

```
id:                  1
stock_logable_type: "Opening Stock",
stock_logable_id:    nil
quantity:            10
```

So basically I left the `stock_logable_id` blank and `stock_logable_type` a string. I don't have any model such as "OpeningStock" in my application.

Even though this works perfectly but i am still unsure whether this is a good way to handle the concerned scenario. Any insights/feedbacks will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your business domain, but I'd rather create an `OpeningStock` model and set `stock_logable` to it. Setting polymorphic type without id may lead to nasty errors.

You can also do STI in `StockEntries` and keep there opening stock then. Or even without any inheritance - you can add state to the `StockEntry` to mark if it's opening or regular.

Comment: Having a separate `OpeningStock` model and a table seems like over engineering. Plus opening_stocks table won't be much different from stock_entries table. Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: You can do STI in `StockEntries` and keep there opening stock then. Or even without any inheritance - you can add `state` to the `StockEntry` to mark if it's opening or regular.

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you create the `StockEntry` first, and no "logable" (I personally prefer "loggable") is available/linked yet, and this is a special *state* called "opening stock", correct? You now seem to use the `stock_logable_type` to reflect this state. This is either because you also have `StockEntry` without a `stock_logable` for a different reason or to make your code/data more self-explanatory?

So if there are other states, I would create an actual state (use an enum or link to a domain table), but otherwise I would just leave the `stock_logable` unassigned completely, and maybe add a convenience method

```
  def opening_stock? 
    stock_logable.blank? 
  end
```

to make your code more readable.